# Why does string-formatted global variable remain the same after changing the variables in the .format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting, tic-tac-toe

New to python, trying to code a game of tic tac toe and ended up in this situation, where I cannot seem to print out a version of my table (multi-line string) with the new O assigned to the position from the input, even after assigning O to the variable at the position.

the code below is incomplete, just focusing on the issue above for now.

```
 mydict=dict.fromkeys(['a1','a2','a3','b1','b2','b3','c1','c2','c3'],' ')
table = '       |       |       \n' \
        '   {}   |   {}   |   {}   \n' \
        '_______|_______|_______\n' \
        '       |       |       \n' \
        '   {}   |   {}   |   {}   \n' \
        '_______|_______|_______\n' \
        '       |       |       \n' \
        '   {}   |   {}   |   {}   \n' \
        '       |       |     '.format(mydict['a1'],mydict['a2'],mydict['a3'],mydict['b1'],mydict['b2'],mydict['b3'],mydict['c1'],mydict['c2'],mydict['c3'])

def assign(i):
    if q%2==0:
        mydict[str(i)]='O'
        print(mydict)
    else:
        mydict[str(i)]='X'

q=2
while q%2==0:
    x=input('Player 1, please choose your position:')
    assign(x)
    print(table)
```

When I run:

```
TIC TAC TOE
       |       |       
       |       |       
_______|_______|_______
       |       |       
       |       |       
_______|_______|_______
       |       |       
       |       |       
       |       |       
Player 1, please choose your position:a1
{'a1': 'O', 'a2': ' ', 'a3': ' ', 'b1': ' ', 'b2': ' ', 'b3': ' ', 'c1': ' ', 'c2': ' ', 'c3': ' '}
       |       |       
       |       |       
_______|_______|_______
       |       |       
       |       |       
_______|_______|_______
       |       |       
       |       |       
       |       |       
Player 1, please choose your position:
```

## As you can see, the O does not appear in position a1.

Comment: Are you trying to print the table too? I see no code corresponding to that.

Comment: @SANTOSHKUMARDESAI, yes, I missed that out. Edited. Thank you

Comment: @MrFuppes yes, it is a global variable

Comment: @AdamO, sorry got confused there. Nevermind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying `mydict` isn't enough, also you need some other changes:

```
mydict=dict.fromkeys(['a1','a2','a3','b1','b2','b3','c1','c2','c3'],' ')
def table():
    table = '       |       |       \n' \
            '   {}   |   {}   |   {}   \n' \
            '_______|_______|_______\n' \
            '       |       |       \n' \
            '   {}   |   {}   |   {}   \n' \
            '_______|_______|_______\n' \
            '       |       |       \n' \
            '   {}   |   {}   |   {}   \n' \
            '       |       |     '.format(mydict['a1'],mydict['a2'],mydict['a3'],mydict['b1'],mydict['b2'],mydict['b3'],mydict['c1'],mydict['c2'],mydict['c3'])
    return table
def assign(i, q):
    if q%2 == 0:
        mydict[str(i)]='O'
        print(mydict)
    else:
        mydict[str(i)]='X'
    print(table())

q=0
while ' ' in mydict.values():
    x=input('Player %s, please choose your position:' % ((q % 2) + 1))
    q += 1
    assign(x, q)
```

Comment: so `return table` allows the values in the string format to be updated after `assign()` is performed?

Comment: @AdamO Correct, it would be helpful if you accept this answer.

Comment: if you modify a string inside a function, you have to return the variable that references to the string to e.g. print it out after the function call (or explicitly define it as a `global`, inside the function). A `dict` value on the other hand is modified 'in place', meaning you don't have to return it. That's what got me confused for a moment. A bit of background e.g. [here](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Answer (score 0):

Formatting only creates a new copy of the string and won’t apply to any further changes. You ought to create a function to format your table and use a base template.

```
table = ('       |       |       \n'
         '   {}   |   {}   |   {}   \n'
         '_______|_______|_______\n'
         '       |       |       \n'
         '   {}   |   {}   |   {}   \n'
         '_______|_______|_______\n'
         '       |       |       \n'
         '   {}   |   {}   |   {}   \n'
         '       |       |     ')


def format_table():
    return table.format(mydict['a1'], mydict['a2'],
    mydict['a3'], mydict['b1'],
    mydict['b2'], mydict['b3'],
    mydict['c1'], mydict['c2'],
    mydict['c3'])
```

Now when you print your table just do this:

```
print(format_table())
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the code doesn't work is because format doesn't get called each time you print the variable table. In order to preserve format and update the string with new values, you need to work on calling it every time. My suggestion would be like the following.

```
mydict=dict.fromkeys(['a1','a2','a3','b1','b2','b3','c1','c2','c3'],' ')
tablestring = '       |       |       \n' \
            '   {}   |   {}   |   {}   \n' \
            '_______|_______|_______\n' \
            '       |       |       \n' \
            '   {}   |   {}   |   {}   \n' \
            '_______|_______|_______\n' \
            '       |       |       \n' \
            '   {}   |   {}   |   {}   \n' \
            '       |       |     '

def assign(i):
    if q%2==0:
        mydict[str(i)]='O'
        print(mydict)
        print(tablestring.format(mydict['a1'],mydict['a2'],mydict['a3'],mydict['b1'],mydict['b2'],mydict['b3'],mydict['c1'],mydict['c2'],mydict['c3']))
    else:
        mydict[str(i)]='X'
```